# TFS 2013: How to set Alert on specific Branch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfs-alerts

Project Alerts are too broad for my organization. I need to be able to set alerts at the branch level, and for specific users.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the Config Option at the top right of the Web Access:

[image]

Then click Alerts and New...

[image]

Select "under a specific path"

[image]

Then enter the branch path against Server Item

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the Visual Studio Documentation. Try this - https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications